# File already used by another process in vb.net using memorystream on my localhost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below is Code.  that convert image into string. I use memorystream and Convert.ToBase64String to get string of image. I also close memorystream object and free .but still also gives error.
The process cannot access the file 'File Name' because it is being used by another process.

```
    Dim obj As New returnresult
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim memstream As System.IO.MemoryStream 
    Dim randomcls As New Random
    Dim strImagePath as string="d:\a.jpg"
    Try                        
        Dim tmpFileName As String = ""

        tmpFileName = randomcls.Next(1, 10) & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strImagePath)

        If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName)) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
        End If

        System.IO.File.Copy(strImagePath, Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
        img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
        memstream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        img.Save(memstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        obj.strImage = Convert.ToBase64String(memstream.ToArray)
        memstream.Close()
        Return obj
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return obj
    Finally
        obj = Nothing
        img = Nothing
        memstream.Close()
        memstream = Nothing
        randomcls = Nothing
    End Try
```

When ramdom class generate same number file and going to delete. it gives me error.

Comment: Replace all your temp file name generation logic with a single call to [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can you explain me brief how should I use this?. because If I am not copy to temp location and directly use that file to convert also give same error.

Comment: I use temp file name logic because I only need 10 files to be created. so can't use it. suggest me other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Remove This Code If possible....

```
tmpFileName = randomcls.Next(1, 10) & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strImagePath)

If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName)) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
End If
System.IO.File.Copy(strImagePath, Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("tmp\" & tmpFileName))
memstream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
img.Save(memstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
obj.strImage = Convert.ToBase64String(memstream.ToArray)
memstream.Close()
img = Nothing
memstream.Close()
memstream = Nothing
```

and write below .....

```
obj.strImage = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strImagePath))
```

. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much trushant.